# Workflow Foundation to separate data from business logic on a mid-sized App?

Tags: c#, .net, workflows, workflow-foundation

We are currently developing a .net app in WPF, that will be a desktop app with a good bit of data-access to local (and some remote) servers. The business logic here is very complex, and currently it is built into the code along with the data access and whatnot (being WPF the UI is separated pretty nicely).

Now, I have been tasked with reorganizing this system to make it more maintainable in the long run as certain logic changes. I know that workflows are supposed to separate the logic out pretty nicely and allow you to visualize it a bit. Is workflow a good choice for an app that does not need to be run over long periods? (since workflows **can** wait in idle for months) What has been your experience with the platform? Is it slow for dealing with a mid-sized company; around 150 simultaneous users? If you liked it, do you know of any good online tutorials (preferably not MSDN) that can give me a taste for the platform and do some testing before I commit to implementing it on a huge app?

Comment: Considering that the word "workflow" has a pretty clear meaning by itself, you might want to clarify it in your context. Do you mean you're considering WF (the Windows Workflow Foundation) as a solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have a small amount of experience with WF - creating custom TFS workflows and activities. I found it generally painful and slow to work with - opening a workflow takes a long time (on a WEI 5.9 machine), it often hangs VS.NET, is missing some core features and is marginally buggy.

If you have anything more than a simple workflow you soon run out of screen real estate. I have a 24" in portrait orientation (1200x1920) and often found myself wanting more vertical room.

Overall I found it pretty frustrating and wouldn't recommend it. It didn't seem to allow me to do anything that I couldn't have done more easily in code.

Comment: Thanks. Do you know which version you were using? The workflow foundation with VS 2010 and .Net 4.0 is supposedly a rewritten version, so that might be a factor.

Comment: Not sure Inge exact version, but it's vs2010/.net4/tfs2010, so I assume it's pretty current